# Calling Flows from batch apex

Tags: visual-workflow

Is it possible to call a Visual Flow (or Flow) from Batch APEX and pass in parameters?

I can work around it by using REST API and call out to the flow URL with parameters, but is there a programmatic way like calling Interview class or other classes in the Flow namespace?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please check out the documentation for the Flow.Interview class here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/flow_interview_class.htm

They have examples for how to call a new Flow:

```
public class FlowController {

   //Instance of the Flow
   public Flow.Interview.doubler myFlow {get; set;}
   public Double value {get; set;}

   public Double getOutput() {
      if (myFlow == null) return null;
      return (Double)(myFlow.getVariableValue('v1'));
   }

   public void start() {
      Map<String, Object> myMap = new Map<String, Object>();
      myMap.put('v1', input);
      myFlow = new Flow.Interview.doubler(myMap);  <== Instantiate with params
      myFlow.start();                              <== Start flow!
   }
}
```